# Django Aggregate- Division with Zero Values

Tags: django, django-queryset

I am using Django's [aggregate query expression](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/models/expressions/) to total some values. The final value is a division expression that may sometimes feature zero as a denominator. I need a way to escape if this is the case, so that it simply returns 0.

I've tried the following, as I've been using something similar my annotate expressions:

```
from django.db.models import Sum, F, FloatField, Case, When

def for_period(self, start_date, end_date):
    return self.model.objects.filter(
        date__range=(start_date, end_date)
    ).aggregate(
        sales=Sum(F("value")),
        purchase_cogs=Sum(F('purchase_cogs')),
        direct_cogs=Sum(F("direct_cogs")),
        profit=Sum(F('profit'))
    ).aggregate(
        margin=Case(
            When(sales=0, then=0),
            default=(Sum(F('profit')) / Sum(F('value')))*100
        )
    )
```

However, it obviously doesn't work, because as the error says:

> 'dict' object has no attribute 'aggregate'

What is the proper way to handle this?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

This will obviously not work; because `aggregate` returns a dictionary, not a QuerySet (see the [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/models/querysets/#aggregate)), so you can't chain two `aggregate` calls together.

I think using [`annotate`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/models/querysets/#annotate) will solve your issue. `annotate` is almost identical to `aggregate`, except in that it returns a QuerySet with the results saved as attributes rather than return a dictionary. The result is that you can chain `annotate` calls, or even call `annotate` then `aggregate`.

So I believe something like:

```
return self.model.objects.filter(
    date__range=(start_date, end_date)
).annotate(  # call `annotate`
    sales=Sum(F("value")),
    purchase_cogs=Sum(F('purchase_cogs')),
    direct_cogs=Sum(F("direct_cogs")),
    profit=Sum(F('profit'))
).aggregate(  # then `aggregate`
    margin=Case(
        When(sales=0, then=0),
        default=(Sum(F('profit')) / Sum(F('value')))*100
    )
)
```

should work.

Hope this helps.

Comment: This looks like it ought to work, but doesn't quite yet, due to an issue with Django. I think I'll need to put these into two operations for now. https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/django-updates/3YQKFNTmzrU/CP0eF_KwAwAJ

Comment: I should note that I am using Django 1.8 and it may very well be fixed in the latest release.

Answer (score 4):

I've made it work (in Django 2.0) with:

```
from django.db.models import Case, F, FloatField, Sum, When

aggr_results = models.Result.objects.aggregate(
    at_total_units=Sum(F("total_units")),
    ag_pct_units_sold=Case(
        When(at_total_units=0, then=0),
        default=Sum("sold_units") / (1.0 * Sum("total_units")) * 100,
        output_field=FloatField(),
    ),
)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can't chain together aggregate statements like that. The docs say:

> aggregate() is a terminal clause for a QuerySet that, when invoked,
>   returns a dictionary of name-value pairs.

It returns a python dict, so you'll need to figure out a way to modify your query to do it all at once. You might be able to replace the first call to aggregate with `annotate` instead, as it returns a queryset:

> Unlike aggregate(), annotate() is not a terminal clause. The output of
>   the annotate() clause is a QuerySet

As for the division by 0 possibility, you could wrap your code in a try catch block, watching for `ZeroDivisionError`.