# Django recurring record/payment calculation

Tags: python, django, django-queryset

I have a table of "expected payments" that either are a one-time payment, or recurring monthly, quarterly or yearly. The goal is to calculate the total amount of expected payments for each of the upcoming 12 months.

The model looks like:

```
class ExpectedPayment(models.Model):
    id = models.BigIntegerField(primary_key=True)
    period = models.BigIntegerField()
    date_start = models.DateField(blank=True, null=True)
    date_end = models.DateField(blank=True, null=True)
    amount = models.DecimalField(max_digits=1000, decimal_places=1000)
```

Period 1 = Monthly recurring 
Period 2 = Every Quarter - Following the start date. (So started on February, next quarter is May)
Period 3 = Yearly recurring - Also following the start date
Period 4 = One time payment

How can I properly calculate the total "amount" for each month, while taking into account when a payment should take place? Especially the quarterly payments..

I can't figure out how to incorporate when a payment has been started and ended, as it might have been started halfway throughout the year, ended 3 months later or was already finished in the first place. How do I know which month the quarterly should count as an expected payment, when it is always relative to its start_date.

An example for a single month: (every monthly payment that is active in the current month)

```
start_of_current_month = datetime.today().replace(day=1)
current_month_expected_monthly_payments = ExpectedPayment.objects.filter(period=1, date_start__lte=start_of_current_month, date_end__gte=start_of_current_month).aggregate(total=Sum("amount"))
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming for every given period the payment is collected at the beginning of the period. For example - For quarterly payment beginning in February the amount of February, March and April is collected in February itself. For reporting, you want to report the amount as amount/3 since you want to report on monthly basis. Here is what I think -
For every period you can calculate the amount by using annotation -

```
ExpectedPayment.objects.filter(
    date_start__lte=start_of_current_month,
    date_end__gte=start_of_current_month
    ).annotate(
         monthly_amount = Case(
             When(period=2, then=F('amount')/3,
             When(period=3, then=F('amount')/12,
             default=F('amount')
    )).aggregate(monthly_sum = Sum(F('monthly_amount'))
```

You would not need a separate case for monthly payments since you are reporting amount monthly. For one time payments, the amount will be considered if the transaction took place in that month. Therefore, no separate cases needed for those cases.

I referred to the documentation here:

- [Conditional expressions](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/models/conditional-expressions/)
- [Query expressions](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/models/expressions/)

Here is a [issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39374050/django-aggregate-division-with-zero-values) that uses annotation and aggregation which I think you might find useful.